How to install Conky themes?
I' m asking how to installconkythemes that you download from the Pling store as zip and extract as folders on Linux.
I tried to rename the file name [name]. conf with Anything.conkyrc and then copy and paste the folder to home/. conky, but opening Conky Manager2 does not display the theme I am looking for. The conky in question is Regulus-Dark-PlyrctlF-2.6.

Does How to Install and Configure Conky - Linux.com answer your question? It has detailed step by step instructions.
